# load a cdn hosted index.html onto site and use the cdn's resource instead

Tags: php, cdn

I have an index.html file that is hosted on a paid cdn server, and I want my website that is on a cheap webhost to load the index.html from the cdn server and use the cdn's resource instead.

I've tried:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents('http://cdn-hosted.com/index.html');?>
```

Everything loads fine, but it seems to be using my web host resource instead. Any suggestions instead of using iframe?

the cdn server doesn't render php codes.

Answer (score 2):

That this is served from your own server is totally expected. Your DNS records determine where a resource is loaded from.

If you really want to server you whole site from CDN, then make cdn-hosted.com an CNAME record of your website domain name, ie. www.yourwebsite.com or maybe just yourwebsite.com

Comment: This is correct answer, in that this is really a DNS question.  The OP has in fact concocted a worst case scenario where the end user has to hit both your web server and the CDN (via the web server having to retrieve the content).  So the response to end user is probably at least twice as slow as it should be because the server has to first grab the content from CDN and then re-serve it from the web server. OP would be better off with a simple redirect in lieu of truly resolving the problem at the DNS level.